# Security for MySql with mb_convert_encoding , mb_detect_encoding and UTF-8 encoding

Tags: php, mysql, security, sanitization, mb-convert-encoding

I plan to use code below for adding records into MySql in a secure way.
My questions:

1. I always input my own articles by using admin page's form.
   Since my mysql database and table are encoded in UTF-8, collation:
   utf8_unicode_ci; and all my web pages are charset=utf-8 then do I
   still need first sentence in function (sentence starts with
   mb_convert_encoding ...)
2. 2 - ) Is it possible for a web page viewer, his/her comment input
   into my textarea is not encoded in utf-8 despite my all encodings
   (web&mysql) aer set to utf-8
3. Code below needs any improvement?

   `function safe_input_into_mysql($safe_str)

   {
       
   $safe_str = mb_convert_encoding($safe_str, 'UTF-8', mb_detect_encoding($safe_str));
       
   $safe_str = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $safe_str);
       
   return $safe_str;

   }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In what way do you want the database records to be "secure"? Secure against what?

For communication with a database, you should use parameterised queries. That means there will not be a security risk at the database level. It does not mean the stored data might not be dangerous if used elsewhere (for example, output as part of an HTML document) in an unguarded fashion.

You mentioned that the table character set is UTF-8, but you don't mention the connection character set. You should also make sure the connection character set is set appropriately.

Comment: Unfortunately I know nothing about parameterised queries. try to do things in old fashion. I meant that for example user comments a malicious piece of code. **my first aim** is to neutralize his/her malicious code which will enter my table AND **my second aim** is display characters correctly in my output (in the way that the user exactly meant for special foreign lang. non-English characters like in Spanish or French or Turkish).

Comment: But what kind of code do you mean? If you mean SQL code, use of parameterised queries would put a stop to that, though there are other (arguably inferior) ways of stopping it. If you mean, say, JavaScript code, then yes it looks like your code would prevent them from posting such a thing, although some people might argue that you should escape the data for display at the time it is displayed rather than at the time it is stored. AFAIK, making sure that all of your pages are served using UTF-8 is enough to make sure that users acting in good faith, at least, will submit UTF-8 in their requests.

Comment: to Hammerite:  I replaced htmlentities with mysqli_real_escape_string since my main aim is safe input into mysql. and as I understand from your kind reply, I am ok with encoding convenience also. Am I right?

Comment: As it stands in the code there, $dbc doesn't exist. Also if you aren't going to escape the stored data when you output it, then you need to use a function to escape the HTML /as well as/ one to escape for the database, not instead of.

Comment: to Hammerite: sorry but english level did not allow to understand what you told. $dbc is my mysql connection variable and exists at the very top of my related php pages. While outputting my stored db data, I will use htmlspecialchars.

Comment: OK, I am glad to hear that you will escape the HTML as you output it. When I say that $dbc does not exist, I mean that when you use it in the function it has not been set. It is not passed as a parameter, it is not declared as global, and it has not been assigned to.

Comment: to Hammerite: oh! you mean my function won't understand what it is? So should I make my function function safe_input_into_mysql($safe_str, $dbc) or what do you recommend? thank you so much for answers and patience by the way.